# Steps to design a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I need to know that whether below questions are relevant to ask while I'm designing  a journey. Although below questions are relevant but would they find place in discovery session for journey builder or not.

1. No of messages to be included in a journey
2. Does the business logic requires a single customer to be present in more than one journey?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "data structure" I can only assume you are referring to the Interaction Design, that is, you want to understand what information you need to solicit in order to create your Interaction. Is that correct?

Comment: Question updated to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question to understand is what is their objective? Once you can answer this, then you can quickly identify whether Journey Builder will achieve their objective, or whether another application (for example, Automation Studio) would be more appropriate.

Assuming Journey Builder is appropriate, then you would want to understand:

1. What [entry mode](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/) is required for the Interaction? For example, can a Contact enter the Interaction only once, or only after exiting, or can they exist in an Interaction more than once?
2. How will the Contact enter the Interaction? For example, will they enter immediately after placing an order on an eCommerce website? Or when a new record is created in a Data Extension? This question will help you determine whether it's appropriate to inject the Contact using a REST API method ([events](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html#postEvent) or [contactEvents](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/contactEvents.html)), use an event schedule, or a Fire Event Activity in an Automation.
3. What data is required for a Contact moving through an Interaction? For example, to personalise communications (Send Email or Send SMS activities), or to make conditional decisions about the Contact who is moving through the Interaction (using decision splits). This will inform how you build out your Attribute Groups in Contact Builder.
4. What is the Interaction Goal? That is, what is the success criteria required to evaluate the Interaction performance?

This is by no means intended to be an exaustive list, but it provides some key questions to get you started. I personally wouldn't be asking the "*number of messages to be included in a journey*" — that should be your job as a solution architect to make recommendations in which Activities (and how many) should be included in the Interaction, in order to achieve the defined Goal.